# Is there an 'open in browser' option in the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

There are certain features that are not available in the app such as zooming in on images, and to delete a question we have to visit the web version.

So is there a "show in browser" option? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That feature already exists!

Tap the <kbd>more</kbd> button under the question, then <kbd>Open in browser</kbd>:

[image: Question options]

> There are certain features not available in the app such as zooming image (I don't know if that's possible).

You should also be able to do that in the app. Tap on the image, and it should pop-up in a zoom-able dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have set stackexhange to be the default app for stackexhange links, this just reopens the app. :-(